# Ad is not coming at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have a problem regarding alignment of ad. The ad is coming at top of the app but i need it at the bottom of the app. I didnt defined any layout for ad just directly tried in java. And its working fine but only thing is its coming at top even after  i inserted adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
The code goes as below
       // Lookup R.layout.main

```
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);


    // Create the adView
    // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e36b9902bfcc");

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);



    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);

    adView.loadAd(request);  
    adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: How you got the adUnitId, is it same as Publisher Id, I got Publisher Id but no add are scene, I used your id, it works for me . :-)

Comment: You register your app in the admod site, there u'll get that..I have done it long back so not sure in site where u can find..Just try around after adding ur app u'll get for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the parameters when you add the view to the relative layout

Change

```
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
```

to

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE); 
    layout.addView(adView,params);
```

Comment: you said you want it on bottom? why sad?

Comment: Hey thanks sherif its working now , i had forgot  adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); to add as i was trying somethin.... Thanks lot dude. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `LayoutParams` of your `RelativeLayout` to :

```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=
       new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```